# get difference between two rows and populate the difference value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3ue3.jpg)I have a table with the below structure.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
I want to calculate one more column name it has "Difference". The difference should be calculated if the guid values are same and populate the difference on both rows.

After the Difference column my table should look like below
[image]

GIving more details

My table looks like below

```
GUID                                    Date      Quantity
0001639C-8047-45FD-8FB0-D24B906D25D0    7/21/2016   30
0001639C-8047-45FD-8FB0-D24B906D25D0    7/15/2016   20
00088951-A2F6-4405-9195-4E830912D56D    7/22/2016   40
00088951-A2F6-4405-9195-4E830912D56D    7/12/2016   20
00060D8A-F711-42BD-824F-6F9F92A02E6E    7/23/2016   2
00074492-6068-48A6-8F99-F70D7328B166    7/19/2016   15
0007E203-4BD9-4937-BFCB-6A3EBCA33448    7/15/2016   2
```

After Calculating the difference column it should look like below

```
GUID               Date                                 Quantity    Difference
0001639C-8047-45FD-8FB0-D24B906D25D0    7/21/2016        30                10
0001639C-8047-45FD-8FB0-D24B906D25D0    7/15/2016        20                10
00088951-A2F6-4405-9195-4E830912D56D    7/22/2016        40                20
00088951-A2F6-4405-9195-4E830912D56D    7/12/2016        20                20
00060D8A-F711-42BD-824F-6F9F92A02E6E    7/23/2016         2                 0
00074492-6068-48A6-8F99-F70D7328B166    7/19/2016        15                 0
0007E203-4BD9-4937-BFCB-6A3EBCA33448    7/15/2016     2                     0
```

The difference column should be calculated when the guid values are same ,the difference in the quantity should be performed and it should be populated in the difference column .If the guid values are not same then it should be populated with zero.

Comment: please add  difference column in output  ,should the guid be checked only with next row for equality ?

Comment: arent both picture the same? and use text data. We cant copy/paste from pictures.

Comment: Added the Difference column image as well and provided more details.Let me know if those are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table Table (GUID varchar(50), Date Date, Quantity Decimal(9,2))
Insert Into @Table (GUID,Date,Quantity) Values
('0001639C-8047-45FD-8FB0-D24B906D25D0','2016-07-21',30),
('0001639C-8047-45FD-8FB0-D24B906D25D0','2016-07-15',20),
('00088951-A2F6-4405-9195-4E830912D56D','2016-07-22',40),
('00088951-A2F6-4405-9195-4E830912D56D','2016-07-12',20),
('00060D8A-F711-42BD-824F-6F9F92A02E6E','2016-07-23',2),
('00074492-6068-48A6-8F99-F70D7328B166','2016-07-19',15),
('0007E203-4BD9-4937-BFCB-6A3EBCA33448','2016-07-15',2)

;with cteBase as (
  Select *
        ,Difference=Quantity - Lag(Quantity) over (Partition By GUID Order By Date)
        ,PctChange =(100*(Lag(Quantity) over (Partition By GUID Order By Date)))/Quantity
   From  @Table
)
Select GUID,Date,Quantity
      ,Difference = sum(isnull(Difference,0)) over (Partition By GUID Order By Date Desc)
      ,PctChange  = sum(isnull(PctChange ,0)) over (Partition By GUID Order By Date Desc)
 From cteBase
 Order by GUID,Date Desc
```

Returns

```
GUID                                    Date        Quantity  Difference    PctChange
0001639C-8047-45FD-8FB0-D24B906D25D0    2016-07-21  30.00     10.00         66.666666666666
0001639C-8047-45FD-8FB0-D24B906D25D0    2016-07-15  20.00     10.00         66.666666666666
00060D8A-F711-42BD-824F-6F9F92A02E6E    2016-07-23  2.00      0.00          0.000000000000
00074492-6068-48A6-8F99-F70D7328B166    2016-07-19  15.00     0.00          0.000000000000
0007E203-4BD9-4937-BFCB-6A3EBCA33448    2016-07-15  2.00      0.00          0.000000000000
00088951-A2F6-4405-9195-4E830912D56D    2016-07-22  40.00     20.00         50.000000000000
00088951-A2F6-4405-9195-4E830912D56D    2016-07-12  20.00     20.00         50.000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table Table (GUID varchar(50), Date Date, Quantity Decimal(9,2))
Insert Into @Table (GUID,Date,Quantity) Values
('0001639C-8047-45FD-8FB0-D24B906D25D0','2016-07-21',30),
('0001639C-8047-45FD-8FB0-D24B906D25D0','2016-07-15',20),
('00088951-A2F6-4405-9195-4E830912D56D','2016-07-22',40),
('00088951-A2F6-4405-9195-4E830912D56D','2016-07-12',20),
('00060D8A-F711-42BD-824F-6F9F92A02E6E','2016-07-23',2),
('00074492-6068-48A6-8F99-F70D7328B166','2016-07-19',15),
('0007E203-4BD9-4937-BFCB-6A3EBCA33448','2016-07-15',2)

;with cteBase as (
  Select *
        ,Difference=Quantity - Lag(Quantity) over (Partition By GUID Order By Date)
   From  @Table
)
Select GUID,Date,Quantity
      ,Difference = sum(isnull(Difference,0)) over (Partition By GUID Order By Date Desc)
 From cteBase
 Order by GUID,Date Desc
```

Returns

```
GUID                                    Date        Quantity    Difference
0001639C-8047-45FD-8FB0-D24B906D25D0    2016-07-21  30.00       10.00
0001639C-8047-45FD-8FB0-D24B906D25D0    2016-07-15  20.00       10.00
00060D8A-F711-42BD-824F-6F9F92A02E6E    2016-07-23  2.00        0.00
00074492-6068-48A6-8F99-F70D7328B166    2016-07-19  15.00       0.00
0007E203-4BD9-4937-BFCB-6A3EBCA33448    2016-07-15  2.00        0.00
00088951-A2F6-4405-9195-4E830912D56D    2016-07-22  40.00       20.00
00088951-A2F6-4405-9195-4E830912D56D    2016-07-12  20.00       20.00
```

Comment: Want to add one column ,

Comment: Want to add one column ,@John % increase Column need to added .The column logic can be like when the guid values are same the % column should be calculated in this way (20/30) * 100 = 66 .The column should be populated as 66 .And if guid are different the % column should be blank or zero

Comment: Added another answer